# Passing a list of values to a function

Tags: python

Sorry for such a silly question, but sitting in front of the comp for many hours makes my head overheated, in other words — I'm totally confused. 
My task is to define a function that takes a list of words and returns something.
How can I define a function that will take a list of words?

```
def function(list_of_words):
    do something
```

When running this script in Python IDLE we should suppose to write something like this:

```
>>> def function('this', 'is', 'a', 'list', 'of', 'words')
```

But Python errors that the function takes one argument, and six (arguments) are given.
I guess I should give my list a variable name, i.e. `list_of_words = ['this', 'is', 'a', 'list', 'of', 'words']`, but ... **how?**

Comment: Sure you are not supposed to call your function like `function(['this','is','a', 'list'])`?

Comment: it would be easier to understand your question if you would label your first code block. Is it a specification of the task to be done? Is it a failed attempt at implementation?

Comment: are you trying to ask, how do you define a function that can be called with a series of separate arguments (words), and the function receives them as a list?

Comment: @  mikerobi - how would you consider this silly question to be a homework?
@ LarsH - I am trying to make ny code to be called with a list of words.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Simply call your function with:

```
function( ['this', 'is', 'a', 'list', 'of', 'words'] )
```

This is passing a list as an argument.

Comment: THIS IS WHAT I NEED! THANKS A LOT, I WAS TOTALLY CONFUSED.

Comment: @Gusto: [ur caps r on, btw](http://news.cnet.com/oprah-gets-pwned-by-shaq-on-twitter/)

Answer (score 9):

Use code:

```
def function(*list_of_words):
     do something
```

list_of_words will be a tuple of arguments passed to a function.

Comment: maybe this one is correct too, but since I don't know what tuple is, I won't use it in my code

Comment: Maybe learn what it is? A tuple is simply a collection of items, the container of which cannot be shrunk or expanded. Similar to a list, but without `.append()` or `.remove()`, if you will.

Answer (score 2):

It's simple:

```
list_of_words = ['this', 'is', 'a', 'list', 'of', 'words']
def function(list_of_words):
    do_something
```

That's all there is to it.

Comment: that's what I thought he was asking too, but it sounds like maybe he meant that each word should be passed as a separate argument to the function.

Comment: The task is to take a (some/any) list of words, not a specific one.

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> def function(list_of_words):
...     print( list_of_words )
... 
>>> 
>>> function('this', 'is', 'a', 'list', 'of', 'words')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: function() takes exactly 1 argument (6 given)
>>> function(['this', 'is', 'a', 'list', 'of', 'words'])
['this', 'is', 'a', 'list', 'of', 'words']
```

Works for me.  What's going wrong for you?  Can you be **specific** on what doesn't work for you?

Comment: you're right, I should put it in square brackets - this is the answer to mu question.
P.S. I'm a beginner so don't judge)